# How can I configure apache2 to use a non - exportable ssl certificate managed by windows?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, ssl-certificate

On Windows Server 2008 R2, my IT administrator has installed a certificate using the windows certificate management tool. The certificate is for *.thedomain.com. He set it up as not exportable for security reasons: I'm not suposed to be able to put my hands on the certificate.

This configuration would allow me to use the certificate with microsoft products, but not to go away with the certificate.

Q: It there a way to configure Apache 2 to use this certificate "the windows way"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache uses OpenSSL to manage SSL/TLS security as well as for managing certificates and OpenSSL does not use the windows certificate store so there are no easy way to implement what you request.

So, in your case, the simpler solution would be to offload SSL encryption to a reverse proxy that uses the Windows store (you can [use IIS and ARR](http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2010/04/01/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx) for that. It's not trivial but it isn't too complex either).

**However**, I'm not sure that would be the proper solution to adopt from an architecture and security point of view.

It makes a lot of sense for your administrator to wish to restrict access to the private key linked to your domain wildcard certificate. It makes a lot less sense, however, to do so by installing it the way he does: unless he gave you no admin rights on that server, you will still be able to recover that certificate data from the machine if you put your mind to it.

So, the best solution, from my point of view, would be for him to setup a separate system dedicated to performing SSL termination (i.e. a SSL-enabled reverse HTTP proxy) on a system he control. You can then either setup your Apache server as a simple HTTP server and the proxy will take care of the encryption.

If your requirements or policies do not allow for cleartext network traffic between your proxy and your web server, than you can setup a self-signed SSL certificate for your apache system and have your reverse trust it (actually any x509 certificate will do: if you have an internal CA, it can be used as well).

This way, you're keeping the responsibilities of everyone properly segregated.

Comment: This is not the news I hoped for, but it makes sense, thank you.

Comment: Don't despair: setting up a reverse proxy for terminating SSL connection is actually common practice: it makes a lot of sense from a lot of point of view. Have a discussion with your network support staff about it and you might be surprised how open they could be to the solution.

Comment: Lol do I look despaired? That's what I'm about to do. Thanks for the insights.